# symfony swiftMailer

Tags: symfony, sendmail

Всем привет, какие варианты есть решения такой проблемы. Есть стандартный конфигурационый файл в parameters для отправки почты. Но теперь встала задача чтобы каждый пользователь мог настроить свою почту и выбирать с какой отправлять..

Я решил сделать для этого таблицу в базе и сохранять туда нужные поля. 
До этого передавалось примерно так:

```
<argument type="collection">
    <argument key="payments_mailer" type="service" id="swiftmailer.mailer.payments_mailer" />
    <argument key="remote_clients_mailer" type="service" id="swiftmailer.mailer.remote_clients_mailer" />
    <argument key="main_mailer" type="service" id="swiftmailer.mailer.main_mailer" />
</argument>
<argument>%parameters.mailers%</argument>
```

Теперь же я добавил ещё сам SwiftMailer в сервис и разделил функцию send на две функции в второй где мне прийдётся конфигурировать swiftMailer с параметрами пользователя.

Вопрос как это лаконичнее можно сделать? Хороший вариант ли сохранять в бд а не в конфиге такие параметры? ( просто я подумал что в конфиг для всех пользователей нет смысла писать).

Comment: Не знаю верно ли я подскажу вам сам, но я думаю что настройки для  swiftMailer вам менять и не нужно. Вся логика в том, что бы пользователь мог просто задавать динамически параметр `setFrom('send@example.com')` и менять текст сообщения.

Comment: Да я так и сделал)